# How to check for similar elements (may not be identical and of different lengths) between a list and a series

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I have a dataframe and a list as followed:

```
# Set up df
series1 = pd.Series(['orange','apple pie', 'freshly imported pear','grapes','dragonfruit','exotic mango'])
series2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product': series1, 'ID': series2})

# Set up list
lst = ['local pear','orange juice' , 'made from real grapes', 'apple', 'pineapple pen', 'banana mama']
```

My wish is to create a new column in the dataframe that shows whether each product in the dataframe is in the list (Yes or No). It's a 'Yes' if there is any match of sub-strings at all.

My desired output is:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'Product': series1, 'ID': series2, 'Matched': pd.Series(['yes','yes','yes','no','no','no'])})
```

I have tried:

```
for v in lst:
    for u in df['Product']:
        if u in v or v in u:
            df['Matched'] = 'yes'
        else:
            df['Matched'] = 'no'
```

The problem is that the result is overwritten for each loop iteration and I don't know how to fix this it. Because the items have different lengths, writing 'u in v or v in u' is my way of getting around it but it doesn't seem right. Please help

Comment: `orange` is not in the list.

Comment: it's 'orange juice'

Comment: So `orange` is yes because is in `orange juice`?

Comment: Yes, as long as there is a word match, we record it as yes